# Invisible Revisions

Tags: discussion, edits, design

I got a notice a few moments ago which said an edit had been made to [Cleansing User Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527).

Upon checking the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36628418/revisions) I saw no differences:

[image: invisible edit]

Of course this made me more curious, so I copied the [revision source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ae2fec6d-28e0-4781-b12f-ca21e28b9432/view-source) and pasted it into my text editor because the edit said 208 characters were added to the body. Here is what I saw:

[image: dashing through the snow!]

208 dashes have been added to the question and they are not visible in the question itself. Nor are they visible when you click edit on the question.

[image: invisible in the edit pane too]

From my POV it seems someone has found a way to claim they made edits without having to make any edits at all. Would this be considered "gaming the system"? Or is it just a bug of some sort?

Comment: [Very suspicious edits...](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7275984/siam?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Comment: Yeah, that is not good. Please flag for a moderator.

Comment: It seems that making points from nothing is like playing Farmville; no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: aside from getting a badge why increase your edit count? it's not like anyone reads how many edits a person has made in the edit review queue and the user is above the threshold to gain rep from edits

Comment: @Fred-ii- They're not getting any points for it; they're just bumping the question and having their name marked as the most recent editor.  I expect that if they're doing this intentionally (and they might not be), it's probably because of the bumping effect (which of course can be of value to people).

Comment: @Servy I stand corrected; that's what I meant; as in "them getting exposure", the editor.

Comment: @Memor-X I do notice especially for poor edits, which I use to investigate and [gently remind users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713837/jquery-using-html-to-past-ajax-data-in-table/42713892#comment72549710_42713892) if they have been making poor edits.

Comment: @Memor-X maybe they didn't notice they reached their maximum when they started this at the end of february: http://stackoverflow.com/users/7275984/siam?tab=reputation

Comment: Looking at the user's profile, i'd assume he's just playing the game. relatively new, very active user.

Comment: Game over then.

Comment: At least one edit is problematic: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/332365/revisions

Comment: One would need to ping the person(s) in question and ask them why they did that. If they're not going to respond or responds with an invalid reason, then a moderator should get involved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- A moderator will need to get involved either way, given the scope of the vandalizm.

Comment: @Servy If they are scored, then given the amount done, they should be stripped of their "privilege" to edit, on a set time basis; we'll leave that up to the mods.

Comment: Given the number of edits in the past couple of hours it looks like the user has figured out how to automate these "revisions". The number of characters per edit seem to suggest he is working on some sort of algorithm.

Comment: Given that the user comes from [TRAPPIST-1f](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7275984/siam?tab=profile) I guess it's safe to say that a) aliens exist and b) they are smart enough to trick us using our own flawed Unicode system. I guess it was just a matter of time ...

Comment: View source code of the revision source: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ae2fec6d-28e0-4781-b12f-ca21e28b9432/view-source

Comment: They've been suspended, so I take it that means it's reached the mods, and it's been handled.

Comment: [I wasn't far off...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345750/invisible-revisions?noredirect=1#comment458406_345750) and justice has been served.

Comment: The hyphens in question are [soft hyphens](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00AD/browsertest.htm), they're generally rendered invisible. They can be made with the HTML entity `&shy;` as well. Possibly more evil than the zero-width space in that they aren't considered "white space", nor are they "control characters", they're in the latin-1 supplemental block. Their [intended purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), if anybody is curious, is to invisibly indicate where words *should* be hyphenated during word wrapping.

Comment: The [user's account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7275984/siam) is temporarily suspended for rule violations. Looks like the mods worked it out.

Comment: It appears the goal was to get the archaeologist badge.  All the recent edits were all on inactive, old questions.

Comment: @JeffMercado that explains it though doesn't excuse vandalism. while yes if you go to edit [one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/211383/edit) you don't see it if you look in something like chrome's developer tools the crap is still in the `textarea` so that's still being stored in the database and probably still counts to the character limit

Comment: The user has been dealt with by suspension. Dealing with the results of their edits is discussed in [another question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345775/2157640) that I asked independently, because I did not find this one.

Comment: What I don't understand is how is this vandalism if the post is left in the same state as it was? There wasn't any destructive behavior nor harm.

Comment: But it didn't always leave things in the same state @Braiam. [Look at this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345750/invisible-revisions?noredirect=1#comment458398_345750).

Comment: someone did this to one of my questions as well, I could not find the edits and it said 208 characters added to the body as well, but nothing looked any different. I rolled it back myself. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32568261/15

Answer (score 64, accepted):

All of the invisible revisions have been rolled back by either the community or by me.  In the future, if you see something like this you can flag one of the posts for moderator attention using the Other flag and explain the situation.  The mods will handle it as needed.

Answer (score 53):

The user inserted invisible [soft hyphens](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad/index.htm) into the original text.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/211383/revisions) for example, he inserted over 350 of these after the first `.`:

```
.%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD%AD
```

All of this still renders as `.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­` <-- point followed by hundreds of invisible soft hyphens.

Not a bug, but rather vandalism, mods should look into it.

Comment: *"mods should look into it."* - [As I stated here...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345750/invisible-revisions#comment458400_345750)

Comment: Once again, Unicode ruins everything.

Comment: Unicode is why we can't have nice things

Comment: The person spotted already here and under 1 month suspension

Comment: Unicode is a .

Comment: @Shog9: There is really an extraordinary amount of anti-Unicode prejudice being expressed here, particularly unjustified since the soft-hyphen is code 0xAD in ISO-8859-1 and therefore is not a Unicode innovation.

Comment: Unicode is like democracy: demonstrably terrible except for all the other options (remember Shift-JIS?  ISO-8859-1 and its evil twin Windows 1252?  *EBCDIC?*).

Comment: HTML Representation: `&shy;`

Comment: Poor unicode...