# Many questions edited without visible difference

Tags: discussion, revision-history

While browsing active questions I noticed many had recently edited by one user. However, the revision logs shows absolutely no visible difference before and after those edits.

[Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/211383/revisions)
[image]

What happened?

Comment: Probably the same thing that happened here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345750/invisible-revisions

Comment: Yes, exactly the same issue, by the same user.

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems they changed `<code>div</code>` to `'div'`. (Except, you know, a ` instead of a ')

Comment: I gotta say, I'm impressed with the way you censored the username without making it look like that's what you did.

Comment: @BSMP Also rather pointless to do when you (by necessity) link to the revision, which has the name.

Comment: @Servy Well I wasn't arguing that it was necessary, just that they did a good job making it look like the text wasn't edited there.

Comment: @BSMP Presumably the edited the HTML before taking a screenshot, rather than editing the image after taking a screenshot.

Comment: @BSMP I censored the image because I have no idea how long those are stored on SO's servers after a question is deleted or revisioned. Wanted to add that into the image description, but then I already got notified of the duplicate.