# User suspended, but edits not rollbacked

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation, rollbacks

Several of my favorite questions got edited by the same [user](//stackoverflow.com/users/7275984/siam) in last 24 hours and I noticed that

- the edits made no visible changes,
- their summaries talk about hundreds of added characters,
- they did not go through suggested edits review* and
- some of them have been rollbacked.

<sup>* The user has rep 1 just temporarily, [due to suspension](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/125271/238706). Actually, [their reputation is well over 4k](//data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/646036/siams-reputation).</sup>

Under closer inspection, I found they added long runs of [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) characters. So just invisible mess.

The user is suspended now, according to the message at the top of their profile:

> This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 3 days.

As I already mentioned, some of these edits have been rollbacked:

- [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array? – revision 43](//stackoverflow.com/posts/11227809/revisions)
- [How does the SQL injection from the “Bobby Tables” XKCD comic work? – revision 14](//stackoverflow.com/posts/332365/revisions)

Still, **some of these harmful edits have not been rollbacked**.

- [What is the strict aliasing rule? – revision 7](//stackoverflow.com/posts/98650/revisions)
- [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex? – revision 3](//stackoverflow.com/posts/701166/revisions)
- [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use? – revision 6](//stackoverflow.com/posts/211383/revisions)
- … and probably many others.

**How should I handle this** (and similar cases in the future)? **Is there an established protocol to cleanup the effects of harmful actions that lead to suspensions?**

- I guess a moderator must have suspended the user, so custom flag seems misplaced here as a mod has already been involved.
- Sifting through the [user’s revisions log](//stackoverflow.com/users/7275984/siam?tab=activity&sort=revisions) an rollbacking manually is labor-intensive, but it seems to be the way to go here. Am I right? I would be OK with that, had it not been just accidentally that I noticed the pattern in the user’s behavior, which had already been *partially* handled by the suspension. I think someone should have already done this or brought it up on meta to get help with that.
- Letting the edits slip through does not feel right. But is that the default approach once a suspension is imposed? After all, these edits will probably be rollbacked, eventually, unless in a very low-profile question.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345750/invisible-revisions

Comment: *"they did not go through suggested edits review (Why? The user has rep 1.)"* Obivously due to the suspension. He originally has over 4k points.

Comment: I'd expect some bulk-rollback by Community♦

Comment: And the user profile now says *"The suspension period ends on **Apr 21 at 9:26**."*

Comment: That question really addresses the same incident, @Pang. I did not manage to find it myself, thanks!

Comment: Suspension leading to dropping rep to 1 temporarily is a feature of the system I did not know about, @Tom. Now I find it has been [documented](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/125271/238706) in [Meta.SE] FAQ. Thank you.

Comment: Although the question is rather different (“Would this be considered "gaming the system"? Or is it just a bug of some sort?”), the answer partially answers my question too (“mods should look into it.”), @Tanner. If that is all to be answered here, I will be happy to close this as a duplicate. Is it so?

Comment: @Tanner (in addition what Paul already wrote) And it asks about the general behaviour in such cases, it just uses this current case as an example. I also don't see a dupe here.

Comment: We've done the needful to address the behaviour. I'm going to ask to see if there's anything the CM/Dev team can do to "silently" rollback edits to avoid bumping a lot of posts again or whether it's best to just leave it as they're (mostly) invisible edits - although, like others have said, that feels kind of awkward. (Although there has been a past case of a well intended script going wrong and bulk editing stuff that required a coordinated community clean up. However, in that case the edits couldn't possibly have been automatically rolled back - these appear to be simpler)

Comment: \*flashes Mortensenlight\* "rollbacked" or "rolled back"?

Comment: Actually, I thought about it, @AndrasDeak. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rollbacked) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rollbacked) led me to believe rollback could be considered a verb. A different query gave me different results. [Rollback on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rollback) does not mention use as verb. [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/154793/57817) and [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/106545/3313) offer deeper explanation. I’ll fix it once I have anything else to add as an edit.

Comment: @Palec What if it is rollbacked after you fix it to rolled back? *ducks*

Comment: What is really disturbing to me is the rapidity with which the edits were performed, suggesting to me the user found a way to automate the edits. It would be a lot of work to copy/paste at the pace the user did. The only other way he could've done it that quickly is by locating the targets and having them open and ready to accept pasted content quickly.

Comment: @JayBlanchard there are existing userscripts that are coupled to editing posts, so it's not hard to imagine that one can script the edits. You just need to open post -> click edit -> click "fill with random non-printable garbage" -> submit

Comment: Yikes! @AndrasDeak Yeah - I really haven't put much thought into that until this started happening yesterday, so I can imagine it too.

Comment: All the edits have been either rolled back by the community or by me. They have been handled.

Comment: Thank you, @bluefeet. Your answer there answers my question too. I joined the vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Seems odd that I can close the question immediately once someone casts a duplicate close vote, but only till I edit it after that. Now, two more votes are needed to really close.

Answer (score 17):

The user has a fresh [Archaeology badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist?userid=7275984). What a surprise! Considering that the user didn't actually deface the posts in question, the most likely motivation for them to perform those redundant edits was to gather badges.

I know it's not straightforward, but it should be possible to confiscate badges that are obtained by blatant gaming of the system. As far as I know only tag badges can be revoked (and only based on tag score), on account of them being coupled to moderation privileges. While non-tag badges don't come with any power, they are the source of much abuse of SO (robo-reviewers anyone?).

In my opinion abusers should be punished where it hurts most. In a month this user will be back and can continue abusing the system in newer ways to obtain the next meaningless (and undeserved!) badge. If they came back and saw that their original abuse was for naught, it might make for a more effective deterrent.

Comment: It would be fun if another user rolls back all the 100 edits and gets another Archaeology badge. (No, I'm not giving ideas).

Comment: *"didn't actually deface the posts"* - not on purpose, but there is at least [one post which got its markdown corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/332365/14)

Comment: @BhargavRao It would be more "fun" if that other user is a sockpuppet of the suspended user ... ;P.

Comment: @Tom , I think the IP got the suspension too. I suspended recetly because of one of my best friend awarded me lot of upvotes from my system. So meantime I created a new ac but the new AC can't had any privilege

Comment: @SagarV I don't think that mods would suspend an IP range so this IP block would only concerns users which keep their IP or haven't reconnected yet.

Comment: As Mentioned, from my system, I use it in chrome, my friend want to become a part of SO, So he created one in Firefox, he continuously give me upvotes then. I suspended and his account locked in `1` but no notice.  I tried creating another account since the Mod is not responding. But it is not working. So I think the IP got a ban

Comment: @SagarV The Browser doesn't matter in that case. Your fried used your computer and therefore your connection to the internet so you shared the same IP. The mod may locked the current IP, but I don't think (s)he locked a certain range, thus reconnecting to the Internet and getting a new IP from the provider would bypass that. (but not the general suspension of the account)