# Questions with invisible characters to workaround title length minimum

Tags: discussion, title, character-limit

[Querying a bit](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/648865) after discovering [Invisible Revisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345750/invisible-revisions), I've fixed a few posts around but I've determined that the following questions have intentionally used soft hyphen to workaround the minimum title length restriction (15 characters):

- <s>[Core dumped?­­­­](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796147)</s>
- <s>[Regex error­­­­­­­­­](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758267)</s>
- <s>[Regex problems­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903445)</s>
- <s>[Http libraries ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809620)</s>

They are all old questions, but one may want to find better titles for them.

And Stack Overflow might want to forbid soft hyphens in titles.

Comment: Personally, I would rather see all of those deleted. They're all either off-topic or too broad.

Comment: I tried really hard to sign up with a username with just soft hyphens. It let me do it, [but this was the result](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7775529/user7775529?tab=profile).

Comment: @NathanArthur I just queried the database and there is no User with a DisplayName including a soft hyphen

Comment: @Cœur Yup. They must be stripping input and then assigning a username when the result of that is empty.

Comment: Both of those regex ones are typo questions and should have been closed and deleted years ago